# Can there be a "100% sale"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm an iPhone developer and I've recently changed the price of my app from $0.99 to free.

Wordnet defines sale as:

> an agreement (or contract) in which property is transferred from the seller (vendor) to the buyer (vendee) for a fixed price in money (paid or agreed to be paid by the buyer);

In this case there is no price in money, so I guess I shouldn't use the word sale. What should I use, then? "A giveaway" doesn't sound nice.

Comment: Are you a good iPhone developer or is there a reason you give your app away? I would like to get in touch with an app developer ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: Being free doesn't mean that the developer is not good , fortunately. :D I am thankful for those apps I could get for free and that are awesome!

Comment: I've got a couple of apps, and making them free is a nice opportunity to get 10-40k downloads, and some publicity + reviews because of it :)

Comment: @mplungjan - as for my availability as an iPhone developer, you can mail me at kolinko@motivapps.com and describe the idea, but I most probably won't have the time to program it for you (although perhaps I may suggest some improvements etc).

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I could approve just one unfortunately, but most of you helped. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MUST use a verb? Because I don't know if there's a single verb in English for that.

There are some "synonyms" like donate, contribute, but they are too general or have different acceptions, which are not strictly related to your request.

If you can use expressions, you could say:

- Available for free;
- Free of charge;
- Gratis.

If you can provide the exact situation where you're supposed to use that verb, I can give you a better answer, I tried to cover all "fields".

Comment: This is the app (currently paid, but I'll be making it free some time in the future). http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sonnet-send-personalised-love/id426006978?mt=8
When I make it free, I want to add "Limited time 100% Sale" to the beginning of the description. "Available for free for the weekend" also sounds nice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for being late. Anyway "Available for free this weekend" or "next weekend" is better because that way you can avoid the sound repetition "for free for"... Those 3 F's are annoying, even if you read them with your eyes and not aloud. :)

Answer (score 4):

Advertise your product as "priceless"

Comment: I'm 99% sure "priceless" is not appropriate (that 1% because I'm not a native speaker so well, you never know), but it's not a synonym of "for free". It means something inestimable, invaluable, having a value beyond all prices.

Comment: @Alenanno It's a pun

Comment: Haha, that makes for a witty ad.

Comment: @jsj I get it, but still... :P

Answer (score 4):

Since you are giving it away for free, I will for once co-operate in a marketing scheme (despite my feelings towards Apple). You could say "download free of change for the next [timer counting down]", or "[same] until [date]", or "introductory price: € 0,-", or what the others have suggested. Good luck!

Comment: I would be careful with "introductory price" because people will think that the app is a demo that not actually free or is a limited version, for which people will have to pay to access.

Comment: @XP1: Hmm are you sure? I usually see that used to promote a product at a lower price for a while, until people get to know it better or it sells well enough. It is the price that is introductory, not the product: I agree that "introductory version" would mean a demo; but "introductory price"?

Comment: Maybe I'm just associating introductory prices with introductory versions. :>

Comment: @XP1: Yeah... that is why I found this marketing stunt a thing to be encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

The WordNet definition may be too specific. A lot of words have multiple specific and general definitions. In general, "sale" could mean "[the sale of goods at reduced prices](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sale)".

If you reduced the price by 100 percent and if the price is $0, then it is still a fixed price in money. It simply means that the buyer does not have to transfer funds because it is free.

I do not have a problem with "100% sale", and I am sure that people would not misunderstand, although you probably might want to say "100% off sale" for clarity.

Even if you are still unsure, you can absolutely use "available for free [for a limited time]", which is what @Alenanno suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Short time offer - available for free/at no cost.

Something like that makes it interesting, yet doesn't make it sound "bad".

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you found is for one use of "sale":

> These items are for sale

WordNet's full item for the quoted definition is specifically referring to *sales agreements* which is a legal term and explains the smattering of legalize. WordNet *also* listed this definition which is probably closer to your intended use:

> an occasion (usually brief) for buying at specially reduced prices; "they held a sale to reduce their inventory"; "I got some great bargains at their annual sale"

You can sell some thing for a price that has been reduced to nothing. Various stores have sales along the lines of "buy one, get one free." Here the reduction in price is implicit because you are getting an extra product instead of paying less.

But, really, when it comes to marketing it doesn't matter much. The point is to get people to pay attention and download your product. "100% off sale!" isn't bad marketing and you will probably get a few chuckles out of it.